# Узнать количество элементов в gtk.ListStore

Tags: python, pygtk, python-2.x

Как в *python* 2.7 c *pygtk* выяснить количество элементов в `gtk.ListStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить не могу, но возможно вот так:

```
len(<экземпляр gtk.ListStore>)
```

Comment: Да! это так. спасибо.